# Laravel 8 Eloquent Many To Many insert into pivot table not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to insert data into the pivot table between **Advertisement** and **AdvertisementCategory**. First of all, yes in my case one advertisement can have many categories.
With this out of the way:

All my Models inherit from my **DatabaseObject** class.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DatabaseObject extends Model
{
    /**
     * Disables the
     * created_at and updated_at column creation
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Here is my **Advertisement** model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Advertisement;

use App\Models\DatabaseObject;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

/**
 * Basic Advertisement
 */
class Advertisement extends DatabaseObject
{
    use HasFactory;

    /**
     * Custom table name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'advertisement';

    public $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'sellingType', 'advertisementType', 'sellingPrice'];

    /**
     * A Advertisement has one AdvertisementCategory
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function advertisementCategories(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(AdvertisementCategory::class
            , 'advertisement2advCategory'
            , 'advertisementCategory_id'
            , 'advertisement_id');
    }
}
```

Here is my **AdvertisementCategory** model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Advertisement;

use App\Models\DatabaseObject;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;

class AdvertisementCategory extends DatabaseObject
{
    /**
     * Custom table name
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'advertisementCategory';

    /**
     * A AdvertisementCategory can have many advertisements
     * @return BelongsToMany
     */
    public function advertisements(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Advertisement::class
            , 'advertisement2advCategory'
            ,'advertisement_id'
            ,'advertisementCategory_id');
    }
}
```

And this is my pivot table object:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Advertisement;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class Advertisement2AdvertisementCategory extends Pivot
{
    /**
     * Custom name for the table
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'advertisement2advCategory';
}
```

And this is the migration creation:

```
        Schema::create('advertisement2advCategory', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('advertisement_id');
            $table->foreign('advertisement_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('advertisement')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreignId('advertisementCategory_id');
            $table->foreign('advertisementCategory_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('advertisementCategory')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

This is the error I receive while trying to insert like this from a request:

```
        $newAdvertisement = new Advertisement();
        $newAdvertisement->name = $request->name;
        $newAdvertisement->description = $request->description;
        $newAdvertisement->sellingType = $request->sellingType;
        $newAdvertisement->advertisementType = $request->advertisementType;
        $newAdvertisement->sellingPrice = $request->sellingPrice;
        $newAdvertisement->createdAt = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $newAdvertisement->images = $allImages;
        $newAdvertisement->unlockedAt = null;
        $newAdvertisement->advertisementCategories()->attach($request->selectedCategory);
        $newAdvertisement->save();
```

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'advertisementCategory_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `advertisement2advCategory` (`advertisementCategory_id`, `advertisement_id`) values (?, 7))
```

Comment: I think your relationship is not `Many to Many` it's `hasMany`, because one advertisement can have many categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is just the order of operations.
You are trying to save record of many to many realtion while the $newAdvertisement is not saved yet, so it does not have own ID (Thats why you are getting error `Column 'advertisementCategory_id' cannot be null`).

First save `$newAdvertisement` and than make relationship attaching.

```
$newAdvertisement->save();
$newAdvertisement->advertisementCategories()->attach($request->selectedCategory);
```

Comment: Thanks this helped, but now I get  a new error :(
```PHP
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`umarketdb`.`advertisement2advCategory`, CONSTRAINT `advertisement2advcategory_advertisement_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`advertisement_id`) REFERENCES `advertisement` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `advertisement2advCategory` (`advertisementCategory_id`, `advertisement_id`) values (3, 7)) 
```

Comment: Found my problem. I had a PK added to the pivot table. After removing it, everything is fine.